# how to display four radio buttons dynamically inside a dyanamically created html table?

Tags: php, html

this my table code

```
$mem=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user_profile WHERE comp_id= $cmp");
 while($result=mysql_fetch_array($mem))
    {
                    echo"<tr>" ;

                    echo"<td><font color='red' size=4> ".$result['fname']." </font></td>";
                    echo"<td><font color='red' size=4 >".$result['emp_id']."</font></td>";
```

inside this table in the third column i tried while loop to show radio buttons.

```
                $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_house where event_id = $eid";
                $hid = mysql_query($query);

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($hid))
                    {
                    $house_id = $row['house_id']; 
                    $house_name = $row['house_name']; 
                    echo "<td> . <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"q1\" value=\"$house_id\" />$house_name </td>";

                    }

                    echo "<td> <a href='house_member.php?operation=dele&id=".$result['profile_id']."'><input type='button' value='add' id='btn'></a></td>";
                    echo"</tr>" ;
                    echo"</table>";
    }
```

its not working properly. somebody please help. i'm just a beginner in php. 
waiting for a better solution.

Comment: Radio buttons should be `type="radio"`, not `type="checkbox"`.

Comment: a question like "its not working properly" will only receive an answer like "try harder"

Comment: also make sure that when you echo mix of strings, you divide them properly, like so `echo "text text ".$variable." text text ".$variable;`

Comment: At least say what "its not working properly" means. If it's hard to describe, make a screenshot (if it's a display-problem).

Comment: sory.. i tried it with checkbox too. that code i paste here.. i think radio is more aceptable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want them all to be in the same column, don't put `<td>` around each of them, do that outside the loop. And the type of the input should be `radio`, not `checkbox`.

```
echo "<td>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($hid)) {
    $house_id = $row['house_id'];
    $house_name = $row['house_name'];
    echo "<input type='radio' name='q1' value='$house_id'/>$house_name ";
}
echo "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

please change the `<Input type="checkbox">` to `<input type "radio">`

and 
`echo "<input type='radio' name='q1' value='$house_id'/>$house_name ";` this is the right way to display html code into php

Comment: if that would be the only error in the OP's code... :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add radio buttons in the third column or do you want to create a column for each radio??

my guess is that you remove the  from within the while loop and place the starting and ending tags outside the while loop. something like

```
<td>
while loop
</td>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following code at the place of your while loop.....

```
<td>

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($hid))
{
  $house_id = $row['house_id']; 
  $house_name = $row['house_name']; 
  echo "<input type='radio' name='q1' value='$house_id' />$house_name ";
}

</td>
```

Comment: Thanks
& also you have to select to my answer because i have post it first.